# Is there a possible way to modify something same in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have these values for each record in a column :

```
http://192.168.106.82/bookclub/uploads/booktype/01_type_education.png
http://192.168.106.82/bookclub/uploads/booktype/02_type_religion.png
http://192.168.106.82/bookclub/uploads/booktype/03_type_technology.png
http://192.168.106.82/bookclub/uploads/booktype/04_type_business.png
http://192.168.106.82/bookclub/uploads/booktype/05_type_healthy.png
http://192.168.106.82/bookclub/uploads/booktype/06_type_magazine.png
http://192.168.106.82/bookclub/uploads/booktype/07_type_literature.png
```

Then I want to modify IP Address 192.168.106.82 to other such as 192.168.1.39
Can I modify all of these in one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with update

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_field = REPLACE(your_field, '192.168.106.82', ' 192.168.1.39')
WHERE your_field LIKE '%192.168.106.82%'
```

Comment: If `your_field` is indexed, they'd probably be better off with `LIKE 'http://192.168.106.82%'`

Comment: @Uueerdo  .. could be  ..  .. but the problem substantially is the same  .. there also other way .. not related porperly  with like ... is possibile use substring .. or other way .. my is a suggestiion clear and immediatelly usable

Comment: Yeah, not criticizing or anything, just figured I'd add it as an sidenote.

Comment: @Uueerdo  .. yes your suggestion is reasonable .. i'm agree ..

Comment: I tried this statement :
UPDATE books
SET imageurl = REPLACE(imageurl, '192.168.106.82', '192.168.1.39')
WHERE imageurl LIKE '%192.168.106.82%'

But I found some errors, https://i.imgur.com/hi8wVxv.jpg

a new statement was found but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near REPLACE)

Comment: Oh sorry, it just a warning but everything worked out well. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions in UPDATEs' SET clauses, like so:

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = REPLACE(field, 'old value', 'new value')
WHERE condition
```

To update the entire table, you would either leave the WHERE clause off entirely, or set a condition that cannot be false (some server configs prevent WHEREless updates).